# probability question is this true?

Tags: probability

So my teacher was solving this exercise and she wrote $D (2x +6) = (2^2)\times D$ 
where $ D$ is the statistical dispersion.But wasnt she supposed to write $ D(2x+6)=(2^2)\times D+ 6$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by Dispersion you specifically mean Variance, notice that:
$$Var[aX+b] = E[(aX+b)^2]-E^2[aX+b]$$
$$=E(a^2X^2+2abX+b^2)-a^2E^2[X]+2abE[X]+b^2$$
$$=a^2(E[X^2]-E^2[X])=a^2Var[X]$$

Comment: Fixed it. I had inadvertently left it out of the $2abE[X]$ factor.

Comment: I love you forever and a day.

Comment: So finding the Var[ax+b] is equal to Var[ax] ?

Comment: Always try and go back to first principles with problems like these. They sometimes just involve some algebra and a fundamental probability concept or two. The "concept" here being that $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E[X]^2$.

Comment: Yes, Var(aX+b)=Var(aX).  Intuitively you can see that adding a constant has no effect on variance because it is added at all points. We are not "stretching" or "contracting" the random variable. Only translating it by a constant. Does this help.